# User in group does not have groups permissions

Tags: linux, permissions

I'm running an Apache web server in Arch Linux. Currently I have web files located at /srv/http and it belongs to user 'http'. The directory is very secure, only root and http are allowed to view and edit the files in /srv/http. Nobody else can view or edit them. (drwxrwx---) I wanted to grant user 'tom' permissions to view and edit so root, http, and tom can view and edit but nobody else can view or edit.

I created a group called 'web' using groupadd command and added http and tom using gpasswd -a command.

As root, I executed "chown -R http:web /srv/http" then "chmod -R g+rwx /srv/http" to set the directory permissions.

The problem is that 'tom' still cannot view or edit files in /srv/http. If I issue "chown -R tom:web /srv/http", 'http' cannot read or edit too. How do I make it so that both users 'tom' and 'http' can view and edit files? What is I am missing here?

EDIT: Ok, I think I figured out the problem. I had to restart my SSH connection that I was using to connect to web server. (basically a re-login)

Comment: what are the permissions on /srv? lots of apps require at least read permissions all the way up the tree.

Comment: If you've found a solution yourself, then please post it as an answer. You'll be able to mark it as an accepted answer after 48 hours. This way other people who stumble upon your question will immediately know that the issue was solved and there's an answer with a solution. Questions are for questions only, answers are for answers.

Comment: Oh, ok, the edit somehow makes sense. Because the chain of permission modifications looked quite alright to me.